# Update a table with result of a select

Tags: sql-server, database

how can I update a column of my table1 with this query?

```
update table1
set table1.column5 = (
select count(*) 
from table2, table1 
where table1.column1 = table2.column4
group by table1.column1)
```

table1 has these columns (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)

table2 has these columns (column1, column2, column3, column4)

and table2.column4 is foreign key of table1.column1

Comment: what you want to update (i.e. in terms of what) ?

Comment: @YogeshSharma I want to update the values of column5 in table 1 (they are integers)

Comment: Your subquery returns more than one value so the update is not possible

Comment: @ElhamKohestani , yes , my select returns a table of integers , how can I insert the integers  into table1.column5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This

```
UPDATE T1
          SET
             column5 = COUNT(1)
       FROM table2 T2
           INNER JOIN table1 T1
             ON T1.column1 = T2.column4
       GROUP BY T2.column4
```

Or This

```
;WITH CNT
AS
(
    SELECT
       column4,
       Cnt = COUNT(1)
       FROM table2 T2
       GROUP BY T2.column4
)
update t1
    SET
       column5 = CNT.Cnt
    FROM CNT
       INNER JOIN table1 T1
          ON CNT.column4 = T1.column1
```

Comment: this code gets an error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.'

Comment: I've added one more solutions, Try that

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
with cte as (
    select column4, cnt = count(*) 
    from table2
    group by column4
)

update a
    a.column5 = b.cnt
from
    table1 a
    join cte b on a.column1 = b.column4
```